# How to get concrete class from a Groovy AST ClassNode?

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have created an annotation and a Groovy AST transformation for it. This annotation is applied for classes only. The transformation works in the SEMANTIC_ANALISIS phase and should create a new class. What I need is to get concrete type (java.lang.Class) of the annotated Groovy class from the ClassNode. But if I try to call `classNode.getTypeClass()` in the transformation's visit method the exception "Getting ClassNode#getTypeClass for MyEntity is called before the type class is set" occurres in the compile time. 
What is the correct way of getting such info?

Comment: In short - you cannot. Please provide details why you need this. 
For comprehensive example how to create new class within transformation please refer https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/rest/transform/ResourceTransform.groovy#L143

Comment: @Dany "In short - you cannot." - I don't think that is true.  How to do it depends on details not present in the question, but it can certainly be done.